# Best way to do a split and convert the result into ints

Tags: c#, string

I have a DB table that contains a comma separated list of ID's (ints) that are stored as nvarchar.

I have a get method to return these in one hit as a list.  At the moment I think I'll have to do something like this:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>();
string[] pageids = experssion.Split(separators)

foreach (string number in pageids)
{
    ids.Add(Convert.ToInt32(number));
}
```

Can anyone think of a nicer way to do this ?  Can I do it all on the split somehow ?

Comment: BTW: I don't get what is pageids variable good for.

Comment: to try and make the explanation clearer.  I stupidly put the split on the foreach

Comment: this is why you shouldn't try to store multiple values in a single db field... it always comes back to haunt you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd to it like this:

```
var ids = expression.Split(separator).Select(s => int.Parse(s));
```

It uses the Linq extensions of .NET 3.0. As an alternative (saves one lambda), you could also do this which is arguably less readable:

```
var ids = expression.Split(separator).Select((Func<string, int>)int.Parse);
```

Comment: Good to see you answering again.

Comment: @Joel: I do my best – but recently I've had very much to do … and that's not about to change. :-(

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using C# 3.0, or aren't a fan of LINQ, you could do it the C# 2.0 way:

```
// This gives you an int[]
int[] pageids = Array.ConvertAll(expression.Split(separator), new Converter<string,int>(StringToInt));

// Add each id to the list
ids.AddRange(pageids);

public static int StringToInt(string s)
{
 return int.Parse(s);
}
```

EDIT:

Or, even simpler as per Konrad's suggestion:

```
int[] pageids = Array.ConvertAll<string,int>(expression.Split(separator),int.Parse);
ids.AddRange(pageids);
```

Comment: You don't need the `StringToInt` wrapper: `int.Parse` can directly be made into a `Converter` object. But other than that, good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ you can do this:

```
List<int> ids 
  = expression
  .Split(separators)
  .Select(number => Convert.ToInt32(number))
  .ToList()
```